# How Do I Create Presentation Decks for Ad Designs? (Plus Another Question)

Tags: print-design, presentation-design, advertising

Question 1:
I often find it difficult to present my design concepts to clients. Specifically, these are ad designs that are essentially the same concept but are alternate versions of that concept. If you had multiple ad design ideas you liked but weren’t sure which 3 pieces to present, how would you make a decision about which one to present?

Question 2:
I still feel like a beginner about presenting my design ideas to clients in person (ex: family members), so often I don’t know how to kick off my meetings with a client, and I also forget to tell them what the next steps are before ending the meeting. How do you facilitate your design presentation meetings?

Comment: Hi Jarod, welcome to GDSE. Please take the time to read through the [help] and [ask] pages. You should limit your question to a single specific focused question, it's likely to be closed as "too broad" otherwise! Thanks

Comment: Okay. I was actually wondering about that as I posted this. But I wasn't sure... so I posted anyways and hoped someone else would correct me on that. Thanks lol.

Comment: no problem, have read through the help pages and keep in mind for future questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, this question is a bit too broad for GDSE, but I'll let you have a couple of pointers before it gets closed...

**Answer 1 :** Selecting the the best option is part of your role as the creative. Any half decent designer can have a load of ideas, only great designers know how to reduce the choices for the customer down to the 'right' solution that fits the brief perfectly while going beyond their expectations. If you're not 100% sure that one or two options that you choose to show will be liked then you can always have some reserve ideas in your back pocket (figuratively or perhaps even literally).

**Answer 2:** A presentation or pitch is like a performance. You wouldn't dream of standing in front of people to sing a song or make a speech without rehearsing so do the same for a business presentation. Practice, preferably in front of a friend or significant other whose opinion you trust and refine the contents and style until you're happy with it. Also, if you have trouble remembering what needs to happen in what order then there is no shame in having a bulleted list to jog your memory.

Comment: Good answer to a complex question. I just want to add to Answer 2:
It is essential to keep the project on one track and not let it branch out. Only one person should work at the time.

- The customer sends you the material.
- You give it your best shot.
- The customer gives feedback.
- You make corrections.
And so on.

Comment: You have perfect answers to all of my questions Chris and Mads Wolf. Thanks so much guys.